# Add text to progress bar

Tags: wpf

[image]

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(strSource);
    FileInfo[] files = dirInfo.GetFiles();
    pgb.Maximum = files.Length-1;
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < files.Length; n++)
        {
            FileInfo tempfile = files[n];
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(strDestination, tempfile.Name);
            tempfile.CopyTo(path, true);
            pgb.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<int>((x) => pgb.Value = x), 
                        DispatcherPriority.Background, n);
        } 
    }));
    thread.Start();
```

I want to show the percentage of copied files on the label of the progress bar where:

```
percent = n / pgb.Maximum
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing this.

Simplest is to create a `UserControl`, and expose various properties from it for showing your message, to set the value of `ProgressBar` :

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid>        
        <ProgressBar  x:Name="PbControl"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TbMessage" Text="... messages goes here ..." HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And in `UserControl` code behind,

```
    public ProgressBar ProgressBarControl { get { return PbControl; } }

    string _message;
    public string Message
    {
        get { return _message; }
        set { _message = value; TbMessage.Text = _message; }
    }
```

Just set the `Message` property from `Window`.

Another option is to create a new `Control` by inheriting `ProgressBar`, and change its `Template`, which I think allows for more customization of your `Message`, but will require more work to do.

Then, wherever you need to set message from another thread, do this :

```
  UserControlName.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { UserControlName.Message = "some text !"; });
```

Comment: You can improve it further by binding the text block text to the progress bar value i.e.  <TextBlock x:Name="TbMessage" Text={Binding ElementName=PbControl, Path=Value}>

Comment: Can I do it in code behind? Not using binding in xalm

Comment: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Comment: Please update your original question describing your error

Comment: How to set percentage to textblock bro  ?

Comment: Isn't a template for the progress bar an easier and better way? This is WPF we're talking about here, after all.

Comment: @cptJack44 set Message value as ` percent + "%" `. what else ?

Comment: @Joey there are numerous ways, beginners need simplest way.